# PHP Can't Read AJAX Posted BLOB FormData File

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, blob

**DESCRIPTION & CODE:**
1) I have **Image Files** like this in my website (created by dynamic jQuery upload):

```
<img src="blob:http%3A//www.example.net/6cf3e4f6-9666-41c8-a588-73f2e5057ee0">
```

2) After some action (e.g. button click) I want to save all these BLOB images on the server. I use **jQuery** code:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('#editor-label-working-area .object_container .image_container img').each(function() {
        var blob = null;
        var image = $(this);
        var file = $(image).attr('src');
        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

        oReq.open('GET', file, true);
        oReq.responseType = 'blob';

        oReq.onload = function() {
            blob = new Blob([oReq.response], {
                type: 'image/jpg'
            });
        };

        oReq.send();

        //(Problem No. 1) This timeOut is used just for test. I need to wait untill XMLHttpRequest is finished.
        setTimeout(function() {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', blob);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'upload_image.php',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

3) On AJAX request I want use my **PHP** code to get the posted File and save it on the server:

```
<?php
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'labels/');

    /*(Problem No. 2) Here I get empty array from $_POST method*/
    $img = $_POST['file'];

    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);

    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.jpg';

    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

    print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
?>
```

**PROBLEMS**
1. Optional problem: In my jQuery code I have to use JS timeout method to wait until XMLHttpRequest created a blob file. This I need to understand how to use some kind of a waiting method that is working some other way than on a random waiting seconds

2) **The main and most important problem**: why my PHP code receives empty array in $_POST method? If I do

```
echo json_encode($_POST['file']);
```

.., then AJAX .success function prints in my browser's console an empty array:

```
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using setTimeout just put te ajax request in the success of the first.
When you append a blob the data is not stored in $_POST but rather $_FILES.

```
    var image = $(this);
    var file = $(image).attr('src');
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

    oReq.open('GET', file, true);
    oReq.responseType = 'blob';

    oReq.onload = function() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', this.response);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'upload_image.php',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    };

    oReq.send();
```

Comment: Thanks saved a few hours for me!